# gnuplottex not recognizing options

Tags: gnuplot, epstopdf, options

I want to use `gnuplottex` to draw graphs in a LaTeX document.
The problem is, `gnuplottex` doesn't accept any options.

A mwe would be like

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,titlepage,twoside,openright,toc=listof, toc=bibliography]{scrreprt}  
\usepackage[a4paper, left=4cm, right=2cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{epstopdf}  
\usepackage[shell]{gnuplottex}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[hbt]  
\centering  
\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=epslatex,terminaloptions=color]  
set xrange[0:3.1415]   
set yrange[-1:1]  
set grid 
plot sin(x)

\end{gnuplot}  
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The `[shell]` option doesn't bother `pdflatex`, but doesn't help with converting the files either (I have to use `pdflatex --shell-escape mwe.tex` to compile).

The `[subfolder]` option is even worse, this produces:

```
! LaTeX Error: Unknown option `subfolder' for package `gnuplottex'.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.   Type  H <return>  for immediate help.    ...                                  


l.54 \ProcessOptions\relax

?
```

I'm using `pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)`

Any ideas what might cause this strange behaviour of `gnuplottex`?

Comment: oh, also I forgot to mention: `\gnuplotloadfile` causes an undefined control sequence... :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `shell` option tells the *package* to use code that requires shell escape. This is the default behaviour, so you don't need to explicitly include the option. However, for security reasons you can't enable shell escape for the *engine* from within a document. You need the `--shell-escape` option.

I don't think the version of `gnuplottex` in TeXLive 2009 had the `subfolder` option. Update your `TeX` distribution to get rid of this problem.

Comment: With some trickery I did update my `TeX Live` distribution (not as simple as I hoped for under Ubuntu 12.04) to TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2012) but that didn't change the error... 
The MWE throws the same error as before and my normal document throws some more undefined control sequences...
That plan failed completely... :-/

Comment: @Knigge46 --- you haven't gone far enough! The version of `gnuplottex` in TeXLive 2012 doesn't have the `subfolder` option. The version in TL2014 does (I don't know about TL2013). You might get away with just downloading the [latest version of gnuplottex from ctan](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/gnuplottex). However, this may cause trouble with other out of date packages. It would be best to install TL2014.

Comment: I am just arguing with myself if I should do that just for the sake of keeping my project folder tidy...  
I actually did download the newest version of `gnuplottex` and unzipped it to my `~/texmf` folder and ran latex on the `.ins` file. I'm not sure if that installed it correctly, but `kpsewhich gnuplottex.sty` says `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/gnuplottex/gnuplottex.sty`...

Comment: Solved it! 
(really some time ago, but now I found the source of it!)

Loading the newest `TeX Live` distribution, and then  putting `gnuplottex` in the right folder: `($USER/texmf/tex/latex/gnuplottex)` and not directly into the `texmf` folder did the trick!
Thanks for your help @Ian anyway!